# как исправить ошибку в ie11 Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference?

Tags: javascript, ie11

вот кусочек кода на который ругается, ошибка такая:

> Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference

Не до конца понимаю что тут не так?

```
var addEventListener = window.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
window.EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function (event, callback, bubble) {        
    addEventListener.call(this, event, wrap(callback), bubble);     
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Как понимаю проблема только в IE11, в остальных нормально? Теоретически <!DOCTYPE html>
И metaтег:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> должны помочь.

Comment: Да, это только в ie11, даже в edge все ок.

Comment: Вот стр на которой эта ошибка: https://giftcards-kroger-stage.qa.ck.ua/shoppingCart

Comment: @Igor я тоже вижу что не суппортится это свойство в ИЕ но не могу понять как по другому описать это?